# Limit the number of DIRECT Instances of a class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, instantiation

To put in other words: How can a class track whether its constructor is called due to instantiating its child class or its instance is directly created?

[Please cosider the following sample code]:

```
class Parent
{
    .............
    .........
    ..............
}

class Child1 extends Parent
{
    .............
    .........
    ..............
}

class Child2 extends Parent
{
    .............
    .........
    ..............
}
```

I want to limit number of direct instances of `Parent` class created by calling `new Parent(...)`, and EXCLUDING from the count, the number of `Parent` instances created due to instatiating any of the child classes `Child1` or `Child2`.

Comment: What's a "child class"?  Do you mean an inner class?  Can you provide some sample code for this case?

Comment: @DmitryBeransky, I have edited my question, Why there was a downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

// in your Parent constructor.
if (getClass() == Parent.class && count.incrementAndGet() >= LIMIT)
   throw new IllegalStateException();
```

Can you explain why you would want to do this?  What do you want to happen when the limit is reached?

Comment: Thanks, this works, of course I have my own exceptions which will be thrown when limit reaches for different classes, thanks for direction

Answer (score 2):

If you care to follow it, single responsibility principle would suggest you separate out this logic of instance limiting, perhaps into a factory class. This would have the benefit of not throwing exceptions from a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
public class Parent  {

    public Parent() {
        if (count.incrementAndGet() >= LIMIT) { //count is an AtomicInt/Long
            throw new InstantiationException("Too many instances");
        }

    protected Parent(boolean placeholder) { //protected means only subclasses can call it
        //do nothing with the placeholder, but it differentiates the two constructors
    }

}
```