# multiple children class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I would like to know some procedure by which I can restrict multiple child classes of a given class in java.

e.g. if I have class A then only one class can extend A i.e. no more than 1 child class is allowed.

I had been asked this question in a company interview and would really appreciate some help or direction.

Comment: Have a look at this SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082860/limit-the-number-of-direct-instances-of-a-class

Comment: No more than one child class, or one child object?

Comment: You can control the number of instances by single-use in an abstract parent class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082776/only-allow-parent-factory-method-to-instantiate-child-classes

Comment: @SLaks: I understand that it's not the same (*possibly the reason why I didn't mark it as a duplicate*) :D What I was referring to is the mechanism can be tweaked since when instantiating a child class, the parent's constructor is also called. Not an elegant approach but it might just work from an interview perspective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to prevent anyone *using* more than one subclass, via the mechanism linked by Sujay (see comments). The superclass constructor/methods could track what subclasses are calling them, remember the first one, and throw exceptions if another subclass is used. Not very elegant, and probably not very useful (but then this is an interview question).

**Update:** Is this what you are after (from http://www.drmaciver.com/2007/09/how-to-create-sealed-classes-in-java/)?

```
public class Sealed
{
    private Sealed() { }

    public final static class Foo extends Sealed {
       public Foo() { }
    } 
}
```

You can't create further subclasses outside of the Sealed class because the constructor is not visible...

Comment: +1 for the Sealed class approach. This is more elegant then the *hackish* way I suggested as part of the comment.

Comment: @DNA thank you for this approach. I tried it and it works fine by restricting further declaration of child classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **Factory Design Pattern** to create instances for the hierarchy of classes and have a **static counter** signifying the number of instances. When the number exceeds your need, throw an **exception** on the factory method.

Comment: That's fine for creating instances of subclasses, but this won't restrict the declaration of subclasses themselves.

Comment: Agreed. I understood the question as the runtime behaviour. IMHO, nothing could be done to stop creating subclasses during compile time

Answer (score 0):

What about when you try to create a child class you use a Factory. The factory can keep some sort of counter or logic to determine if a class is allowed to be created or not. If it is determined that the class can not be created then throw an exception.

```
try {
   ChildClass childClass = ChildFactory.createChild();
} catch (ChildCreateionException e) {
    ...
}


class ChildFactory {

    public static final int MAX_CHILDREN = 2;
    public static int numChildren = 0;

    public ChildClass createChild() throws ChildCreationException {
        if (numChildren < MAX_CHILDREN) {
            numChildren++;
            return new ChildClass();
        }

        throw new ChildCreationException("Exceeded maximum number of child classes");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict this at compiler level. You can "kind of" restrict this at runtime. Create static  variable that will contain `Class` of child. This variable will be updated by base class' constructor. If other child is instantiated the constructor will throw exception:

```
class Base {
    private static Class<? extends Base> childClass = null;

    protected Base() {
        if (childClass == null) {
            childClass = this.getClass();
        }
        if (!childClass.equals(this.getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("More than one child");
        }
    }
}
```

Other solution may be to scan the application classpath and find all classes that extend `Base`. 
Yet another solution is to intecept the class loader, so that the loaded classes will be caught at runtime. The class loader may be controlled either programmatically if you are developing stand alone application or using instrumentation package if you do not have direct access to classloader.

I believe I mentioned here techniques that are not known to your intervier... :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about classes themselves and not class instances,
I think that the only thing you can do is have the class that you want to restrict have a private constructor and declare the (one and only) subclass as a nested class.